How can I prevent iPadOS keyboard shortcuts from forcing my Widget to setState?
My App has some screens which have lots of different Widgets, TextFields, Dropdowns, etc.
I'm experiencing an "issue", where when the user's device is an iPad, the Keyboard has a functionality called Shortcuts, when this option is enabled, the interface displays a small bar on the bottom end of the screen. Whenever the user has focused a TextField and afterwards proceeds to choose an item from one of the Dropdowns (which are Future loaded by the way), every Dropdown on the screen is refreshed, making it impossible for the user to select an item.
I have no idea how to tackle this issue other than asking the user to disable this feature.
Edit: I found out that, for some reason, if you navigate to a route and push a replacement for that route, this behaviour starts happening. If you don't do that, it stops happening. I don't really understand why.
Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Can you provide minimal reproducible code?

'refreshed' you mean the future data refreshed? or selected value in dropdown reset? or unfocused the dropdown?

I meant that the Future data refreshed. I can't provide a minimal reproducible code, I tried to make a small project in order to reproduce the issue but I just couldn’t, I don't even understand how it happened in the first place. For some reason, if I navigated to a route first, then navigated again, this issue would happen. I managed to fix it by removing the first navigation and selecting the initial values on a AlertDialog and then the issue stopped happening. It doesn't make any sense at all.
